# Classic ASP - submitting unknown number and name of fields?

Tags: asp-classic

I have a large recordset being displayed to a user. Each record has an edit button which allows users to edit various data in the record. Certain records have more fields than others so the edit form has various different names and number of fields.

For example one record would produce the following if the edit button is clicked:

```
<form id="frm1" name="frm1" method="post" action="changeJob.asp?jobNo=1101&jQueryID=1" target="_blank">
<input type='text' name='Qty13' value='8' size="3" maxlength="3"/>
<input type="submit" name="btnFrm1" id="button" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

However another record would generate this:

```
<form id="frm2" name="frm2" method="post" action="changeJob.asp?jobNo=1102&jQueryID=2" target="_blank">
<input type='text' name='Qty15' value='8' size="3" maxlength="3"/>
<input type='text' name='Qty16' value='8' size="3" maxlength="3"/>
<input type='text' name='Qty17' value='8' size="3" maxlength="3"/>
<input type='text' name='Qty18' value='8' size="3" maxlength="3"/>
<input type="submit" name="btnFrm2" id="button" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

As above, each of the input fields is assigned its unique name eg "Qty14" and its form has its own name eg "frm2". These need to be unique because I have some jQuery plus and minus buttons which allow users to increment the quantities.

In changeJob.asp how can I determine which fields are being submitted where they have unique names and number? I can get the form name using a hidden field easily enough.

I am trying to achieve something like:

> For Each field in frm1
>   ** Do SQL Update ** Next

Any guidance would be most appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just iterate all the form collection and look for keys starting with the desired name:

```vbs
Dim strSQL, curValue, blnFirst
blnFirst = True
strSQL = "Update MyTable Set "
For Each key In Request.Form
    If Left(key, 3)="Qty" Then
        'prevent nasty hacking
        If IsNumeric(Replace(key, "Qty", "")) Then
            curValue = Request.Form(key)
            If IsNumeric(curValue) Then
                If Not(blnFirst) Then
                    strSQL = strSQL & ", "
                End If
                strSQL = strSQL & key & "=" & curValue
                blnFirst = False
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next
If blnFirst Then
    'no values, show alert of some sort...
Else  
    strSQL = strSQL & " Where [filter here]"
    '...
End If
```

This will build dynamic query based on the submitted values.

If each value need separate update the code becomes more simple, hope you can change it yourself. :)

Answer (score -1):

I would love to help. Needing just a bit more info because I don't want to tell you stuff you already know. Can you tell me if you have code already to fill the form... as in... is this form for editing new and/or old data or only new records?

Also, have you thought of having one form but then have your server-side code (ASP) generate input boxes dynamically? This is my recommendation because having more than one form in this case (unless I'm missing something) is ... inelegant.

You can download this zip file which has two asp pages in it that demonstrate a more dynamic approach: http://www.oceanmedia.net/files/hk_config.zip